# Concatenate null-terminated strings recursively

Tags: c++, c, string, recursion

I'm inventing interview questions that require analysis of C++ code that does something simple with pointers and recursion. I tried to write `strcat()` in recursive manner:

```
size_t mystrlen( const char* str )
{
    if( *str == 0 ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + mystrlen( str + 1 );
}

void mystrcpy( char* to, const char* from )
{
    if( ( *to = *from ) == 0 ) {
        return;
    }
    mystrcpy( to + 1, from + 1 );
}

void mystrcat( char* to, const char* from )
{
    mystrcpy( to + mystrlen( to ), from );
}
```

What I don't like here is that I have three functions and my `strcat()` is not very recursive - it just calls two other functions once. Is there a way to rewrite that somehow to reduce the number of functions increasing use of recursion but without sacrificing much of code brevity?

Comment: I don't think this makes a lot of sense. Maybe you should better find a real problem (simple at that) that can be solved with recursion and do it. Also it is usually harder to write recursion properly than to read it. Trees and any operation on them are usually good candidates. I was asked in an interview how a tree to store integers would be implemented (struct) and then a couple of operations as 'return the sum of all values', 'return the sum of all values at level N counting from the root'...

Comment: Your `mstrlen()` and `mstrcpy()` are going to cause a... Stack Overflow... if given any data of respectable size...

Comment: (Unless of course, you get the blessings of tail recursion optimizations...)

Comment: Maybe the idea of the question is that any candidate who isn't feeling physically ill by the end of the question, has no practical experience of C programming ;-)

Comment: I would run way from interview if I were given such a question :o)

Comment: @Thanatos: Sure, that's one of the comments I would expect from a qualified interviewee.

Comment: `mystrlen` isn't looking good for automatic tail-recursion optimisation. Are C++ compilers typically smart enough to add an accumulator parameter? Is the successful candidate going to do it with a default argument or auxiliary function? This interview is starting to sound like 30 minutes browsing Stack Overflow, maybe you could get the interviewee to do that :-)

Comment: @Steve: I would definitely not ask anyone to write that. I'd rather show them a snippet and ask to explain what it does and how it works. We've been using such questions for a while and found that they're quite good for separating people who only know the language syntax from people who really get how algorithms and data structures are designed and used. Even if people in the former category read this question and learn every letter here it will not be a problem to ask them a very easy extra question on the same problem they'll be unable to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's my example (the advantage is it has only one recursive call):

```
char * mystrcat(char *dest, const char *src){
    if(*dest == 0){
        if(*src == 0)   // end of recursion cond
            return dest;
        *dest = *src++; // actual copy
        dest[1]=0;      // zero out dest buf
    }
    mystrcat(dest+1,src); // advance one char
    return dest;
}
```

here's rough test code:

```
main(){
  char c[]={'a',0,'b','c',0};
  //char c[]={0,'b','c',0};
  mystrcat(c,"xy");
  //mystrcat(c,"");
  puts(c);
}
```

Comment: I came up with something like this for my second answer.  Yours is tidier because it does everything in one direction; mine goes down until it finds the end of the `from` string, then copies characters as the recursive call returns.  +1.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I don't really see the point in trying to make strcat() "as recursive as possible", even though its just for an interview question. strcpy() is just a strlen() + strcat() and the implementation should reflect that. If a candidate gave the solution you have sketched I would be more than happy - he/she showed that he/she understands 1. recursion and 2. using subroutines to implement more complex functionality.

Comment: I agree.  `strlen()` and `strcpy()` both lend themselves to recursive solutions, but not `strcat()`.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
void mystrcat( char* to, const char* from )
{
    if (*to == '\0')
        mystrcpy( to, from );
    else
        mystrcat( to + 1, from );     
 }
```

Comment: I don't quite like the sentence `*to == NULL` even if it works. Dereferencing a `char*` leads to a character that can be 0 or nil (as you wish to call it), but NULL is a *pointer*. I know that in C++ it is actually defined as `0`, but kind of says 'this is a pointer that points nowhere'.

Comment: It is very nice apart from that, though.

Comment: @dribeas - you're completely right, characters should not be compared against the NULL pointer but should be compared against the NUL character ('\0').  Had I bothered to compile this, gcc would have given me an appropriate warning.  Anyway, I've updated my example.

Answer (score 2):

In a single function you could write:

```
// pre: to is a string that is zero-initiallized (all chars are '\0')
void mystrcat( char* to, const char* from )
{
   if ( *to ) mystrcat( to+1, from );
   else {
      if (*to = *from) mystrcat( to+1, from+1 );
   }
}
```

Note that it is intentionally ugly, it serves to purposes in two branches, it advances the `to` pointer in the first branch and it copies values in the other. The if condition is intentionally ugly also as most usually you will flag a single = within a condition as a typo, but insist in that it is up, running and tested so that they must work the meaning out themselves.

One other thing you might consider is adding a return statement like:

```
char* mystrcat2( char* to, const char* from )
{
   if ( *to ) return mystrcat2( to+1, from );
   else {
      if ( *to = *from ) return mystrcat2( to+1, from+1 );
      else return to;
   }
}
```

Now the interviewed has the second task of interpreting the result of the function when called on two strings, and you can discuss how the efficiency of this `strcat` version compares to the original both in terms of single string concatenations as well as multiple concatenations (take a look at [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) by Joel Spolsky that among other things talks about the Scheimel paint algorithm). You can ask for the implementation of this function in terms of both the `strcat` and `mystrcat`:

```
// concatenates a set of strings into a buffer
//
// pre:  to has memory enough to hold all the contents
//       from[i] is a valid C string for all i smaller than n
void mymultiplecat( char* to, const char* from[], int n )
{
   for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
      to = mystrcat( to, from[i] );
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this can work.  It will work just great until it finds the nul character terminating `to`, but then as soon as it copies one character from `*from` it will start trying to find the end of `to` again.  It needs an extra variable to know which state it is in, finding the end of `to` or copying.  My answer was basically the same as this, but with a `bool` third argument to provide the extra state.

Comment: @dribeas: your version will work only if *to in zeroed out until its end

Comment: True, I added that as a precondition. The algorithm can be moved into two functions as @steveha points out, and at that point I would offer a two argument interface that calls on the three argument implementation. Anyway I am leaving it as it is for the added `return` statement and potential discussion.

Comment: Okay, it works with that precondition.  I just always assume that any memory past the end of a string is filled with random garbage, because it usually is.

Answer (score 2):

I thought of another answer!

```
void
mystrcat(char* to, const char* from)
{
    if (*to)
    {
        // keep looking for end of to
        mystrcat(to+1, from);
        return;
    }

    if (*from)
    {
        // make sure we get past first if
        to[1] = '\0';
        // call recursively until end of from found
        mystrcat(to+1, from+1);
        // after call, copy chars on way out
        *to = *from;
    }
}
```

No extra argument to hold state, and it is still O(n).

I'm not sure I could have come up with this while under the pressure of a job interview, though.

Comment: I think the question is more about giving the code written and then asking the interviewed what it actually does. If I ask someone to implement `strcat` and they do it recursively with any of these options, that would say a lot (and nothing good) about the candidate (unless of course the background is lisp)

Answer (score 2):

I had an interview question once where I had to write a simple, recursive BSP tree traversal that was an actual, blanked-out function from a full program.

I'd suggest that something like that would be a better way to gauge someone's grasp on recursion than inventing a problem that's not idiomatically solved with recursion in C++.  Plus it's exciting for entry level applicants when you run the program and they observe their code working flawlessly.

If you insist on going with strcat, I think it could be more interesting if the task was to recursively concatenate an arbitrary number of strings taken from a linked list.  Even if the data copy and string length operations aren't recursive, the traversal of the linked list could be, and I think it would be more interesting as you could actually do work on both the way down and on the way back up.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're done.  You have two lovely recursive functions, and a one-line call to them.

I can only think of a hackish way to even do it in one function:

```
void
mystrcat(char* to, const char* from, bool copy_now)
{
    if (!copy_now && *to)
    {
        mystrcat(to+1, from, false);
        return;
    }

    *to = *from;
    if (*to)
        mystrcat(to+1, from+1, true);
}
```

That almost doesn't suck if you are using C++ and you make `copy_now` an optional parameter with a default value of `false`.  Then the caller can pretend it doesn't have that extra bit of state.

But if the problem is hard enough to make you ask for help on StackOverflow, it's too hard to be a reasonable interview question.  You could ask it just to try to make the person think out of the box, but don't make failure to get a good answer an automatic flunk.

I suggest adding another lovely recursive problem: find the depth of a binary tree.

Given the following struct:

```
typedef struct s_node
{
    struct s_node *pLeft;
    struct s_node *pRight;
} NODE;
```

write a function

```
int tree_depth(NODE *pNode)
```

that returns the maximum depth of the tree.  I was actually asked that question in an interview once and I think it is just the right level of difficulty for an interview.  The people you don't want to hire will have trouble with it, and the people you might want to hire will probably enjoy it.

EDIT: I tested the function and found it had a bug.  This version has the bug fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You want recursion and brevity?  Here's something that I think has both qualities without going too far into the code golf weeds (that's not to say it's not ugly - it is):

```
char* myStrcat( char* to, char const* from)
{
    if (!*from) return to;

    if (!*to) *to++ = *from++, *to-- = '\0';

    return myStrcat( to+1, from) - 1;
}
```

Note that this version has the added complexity of returning the destination pointer (as in the standard `strcat()`).

Here's a slightly more readable version that uses a little less 'pseudo-cleverness' like comma operators and decrementing after incrementing to restore the `to` pointer (steveha's comment prompted me to do this for some reason). On second look at the various answers here is pretty much equivalent to [catwalk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845474/concatenate-null-terminated-strings-recursively/1845609#1845609):

```
char* myStrcat( char* to, char const* from)
{
    if (!*from) return to;  // terminal condition, no more chars to concatenate

    if (!*to) {
        // since we're at the end of the 'to' string, 
        //    append char from 'from'
        //    and 'consume' it from `from`
        *to = *from++;
        *(to+1) = '\0';
    }

    return myStrcat( to+1, from) - 1;
}
```

However, please don't associate my name with any of this code (I claim to have stolen it from someone else).

Comment: Don't do `*to--`, just do `*to`, and then you don't have to pass `to+1` in the recursive call.  Or, you could do it the way I did it, and just say `*to = *from;`, then `to[1] = '\0';`, and then put `+1` on both `to`= and `from` in the recursive call.

Comment: @steveha - there are definitely a number of options.  You just need to take care that if you don't do `*to--` and pass in `to` instead of `to+1` that you increment `to` in the case where it's not pointing to the terminating zero character (ie., the 2nd `if` will need an `else`).  Your alternative using indexing is preferable from a readability standpoint. But remember - I don't claim authorship of this code (it's not an example of good coding style by any means).